# Fixed Effects Regression Constant / Intercept Using LFE (FELM) in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models

When calculating a panel data regression with multiple fixed effects using the `felm()` (of the `lfe` package), no constant / intercept is generated in the summary results.

How can I generate a constant / intercept?

When using Stata (`xtreg`, `fe`), for example, an intercept is generated by default.

(I apologize in advance for not providing a reproducible example...)

Here is an excerpt from Simen Gaure's article in The R Journal (Vol. 5/2, December 2013) https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-031/RJ-2013-031.pdf

"The careful reader has noticed that the behaviour of summary() on a ’felm’ object with respect to degrees of freedom and R2 is the same as that of on an ’lm’ object when including an intercept. *There is no explicit intercept in the result of felm(), but the factor structure includes one implicitly.*"

What if I want the intercept?? How would  I generate it in the results?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use ´plm´'s function `within_intercept` to get the intercept of a fixed effects model. The function`s help page has some references to literature with a formula for the intercept.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `felm` with only one or two fixed effects, I believe you can retrieve an intercept term using the `getfe` function with `ef` option set to `'zm2'`. E.g. using an estimated `felm` object called "result", we can recover the fixed the values of the fixed effects

```
df = getfe(result, ef='zm2')
```

Then the intercept is contained in the row of `df` labeled "icpt" or "icpt.1".

Comment: Thanks! Wasted a ton of time trying to figure this out until seeing your answer.

Follow-up question: can the 'icpt' term be interpreted as the grand mean for that fixed effect? In the case of two fixed effects, why does the other one get returned as a reference? (The documentation here is pretty unclear https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/lfe/html/getfe.html..)